# Simplest Way to Import Data into Script in HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a script in my HTML file that I use to generate a drop-menu. Right now the contents of the drop-menu are hardcoded via an array I define within the script, like so:

```
  <script>
    let select = document.getElementById("selectJob");
    let options = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3", "Job 4", "Job 5"]; // Hard-coded array
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      let opt = options[i];
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.textContent = opt;
      a.setAttribute('href', '#');
      a.addEventListener('click', () => {
        populateJobVal(opt)
      });
      a.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-link');
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(a);
      select.appendChild(li);
    }

    function populateJobVal(val) {
      document.getElementById("selection").value = val;
    }
  </script>
```

What I'd like to know is, what is the simplest way to import that data from an external file? If, for instance, I have an external JS file that returns an array, how do I import that in here and use it within my script in place of the hard-coded array?

Comment: What do you mean by "import"? Maybe use something like AJAX?

Comment: I mean simply, how can I pull in the data from an external file to use within this HTML file?

Comment: So, what about using AJAX?

Comment: Is that the most common, straightforward way to handle this kind of use case? If so, yes, that's something I could do. I don't usually work with HTML files, so was unclear how to do this.

Comment: Have an example you can point me to that does this via AJAX?

Comment: Or just use another script tag, set it's src to the file, then set your list in that file to window.app.list where app is something you use to avoid name collisions on the window object... However, AJAX will allow you more flexibility and control.

Comment: Can I use fetch on a file within the same project? const response = await fetch('../../../some-folder/some-file.json');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with an Ajax call?

```
const response = await fetch('http://example.com/jobs.json');
const options = await response.json();
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
// etc.
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Can I use `fetch` on a file within the same project? `const response = await fetch('../../../some-folder/some-file.json');`?

Comment: You'd better use absolute paths.

Comment: Actually, yes, I think you're right about the absolute path. Trying that now.